# Occurred ArgumentNullException error in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to learn `reflection` in c#, and while learning I'm getting this exception.

```
'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll error
```

> How do I resolve this error?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type customerType = executingAssembly.GetType("Reflection.Customer");
        object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(customerType);
        MethodInfo GetFullName = customerType.GetMethod("GetFullName");

        string[] methodParameter = new string[2];
        methodParameter[0] = "Minhaj";
        methodParameter[1] = "Patel";
        string Full_Name = (string)GetFullName.Invoke(customerInstance, methodParameter);
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name = {0}", Full_Name);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Customer Class code

```
class Customer
{
    public string GetFullName(string First_Name, string Last_Name)
    {
        return First_Name + " " + Last_Name;

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the output of `GetType` method, if your assembly does not have that object.

For example :

```
Type t = assem.GetType("Transportation.MeansOfTransportation");
      if (t != null) {
```

I have taken this code from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx

In short, before making any call, make sure your object/input is not null.

Comment: Thank you @PM , but this only hid my `exception`, but still I'm not getting any output, as you said to check the if the object is null or not,  and with the help of `GetType` method, I'm passing an object i.e. `GetType("Reflection.Customer");`

Comment: I guess the exception is because your `GetType("Reflection.Customer");` is returning null, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think u made a mistake in the below line.

```
Type customerType = executingAssembly.GetType("Reflection.Customer");
```

try printing assembly types and check what is the full name it is giving to customer class.

```
foreach(Type t in executingAssembly.GetTypes())
   {
      Console.WriteLine(t.FullName.ToString());
   }
```